# Drawing basic bipartite graph with Turtle: TypeError?

Tags: python, graph, turtle-graphics

I am getting this error: 
TypeError: setx() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

when I try to run this code in Python:

```
import turtle
myScreen = turtle.Screen()
myScreen.setup(0.5,0.75,0,0)
t = turtle.Turtle
coord_list_1 = [[-200,200],[-200,90],[-50,-20]]
coord_list_2 = [[50,200],[50,170],[300,90],[50,30],[50,0],[50,-13],[50,-73]]
def drawBipartiteGraph(inputList,inputList2):
    for m in range(0,len(inputList)):
        for n in range(0,len(inputList2)):
            t.setx(inputList[m][0])
            t.sety(inputList[m][1])
            t.pd()
            t.goto(inputList2[n][0],inputList2[n][1])
            t.goto(inputList[m][0],inputList[m][1])
            t.pu()
drawBipartiteGraph(coord_list_1,coord_list_2)
```

This may be a stupid question, but I can't seem to figure out why it is outputting that error.  Is there something wrong about the way I have written the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
t = turtle.Turtle
```

to:

```
t = turtle.Turtle()
```